# Where can I find source code for .net CLR and C#?

Tags: .net

Is the source code for Microsoft .net CLR and C# open? If yes, where can I download/browse it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c#.net source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391763/c-net-source-code)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can download the source code of .NET with the help of [Netmassdownloader](http://netmassdownloader.codeplex.com/)

Comment: While I love reflector, I think this deserves to be the answer since it's actual source with actual variable names and comments

Comment: Dang, beat me to it.  +1 from me.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/) to view them.

Or, if you have Resharper 5 installed, you can [download the source cod](http://resharper.blogspot.com/2009/10/resharper-5-less-shifting-means-more.html)e for viewing purpose.

[image]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/external_sources_crop.png))</sub>

***But no, it is not open source, despite that you can download and view the source code.***

Answer (score 7):

Part of .NET Core is now open-source, starting with .NET Core 5.0.
Here is the project site: http://www.dotnetfoundation.org/netcore5
Here is the code: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx

Answer (score 4):

While I'm not intimately familiar with the licensing of Microsoft's available source code, there is at least one *implementation* of the CLR and C# compiler that is open source -- Novell's Mono.

http://www.mono-project.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at the official one: [Microsoft Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

You can browse the source code in Visual Studio as well, while debugging. To enable this feature, follow the steps described here: [Configure Visual Studio 2013 for debugging .NET framework](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

for BCL you can check [here](https://bcl.codeplex.com/) (codeplex)

and for the CLR it self [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) (githup)

Comment: its not clr its coreclr which is different