# c#.net source code

Tags: c#, .net

is it possible to see the source code of C# library implementations?

such as List or Dictionary implementation source code.

Comment: Wait, did anyone suggest Reflector?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to open up anything in Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and view any of the framework source.

Comment: .NET Reflector is no longer free.  I use [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) instead, which is just as good as .NET Reflector was when it was free.

Answer (score 21):

You can download the entire Microsoft .NET Framework Sourcecode at [Microsoft's Reference Source Code Center](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. ReSharper helps by automatically downloading the pdb, if it is availabe from Microsoft, when you hit F12. Otherwise you can use Reflector.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

There is a free version.

There are other ways, like the Mono or Rotor source.  In my opinion, Reflector is the simplest and most useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. You can decompile every .NET Assembly using [Red Gates Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) together with the [appropriate AddIns](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflector for this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go one step further than reflector and actually step into the framework code while debugging, then check out this blog post from Scott Guthrie: [.NET Framework Library Source Code now available](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx).

It tells you how to use the Microsoft Symbol servers to get the framework code while debugging.